# Can CSS classes defined be referenced inside a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `.js` Javascript file, inside which I reference CSS classes defined in a separate stylesheet file.

By referencing, I mean something like this:

`.attr("class", "link")`

where `link` is a class defined in the stylesheet file.

If I link both the `.js` and `.css` files above inside a `.html` file, would the styles be applied properly?

**EDIT**: what I've tried so far

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Graph Test</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="../css/graph.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="graph-container">
            <div style="width:700px; height:600px" id="graph"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/2.10.0/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/graph1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`graph1.js` is the `.js` file in question, in which I reference classes from `graph.css`. Both files are present at specified locations, yet no styles defined in `graphs.css` is applied to the elements created by `graph1.js`.

Note: take off `<!DOCTYPE html>` eliminates the problem, but it's not a solution.

Comment: won't don't you give it a try?

Comment: Probably, yes. Did you already try? Also, if you keep having issues, please show some code.

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by "reference"? Do you want to modify the classes from js?

Comment: -1 because "This question does not show any research effort" as per the downvote hover text.

Comment: @Ibu, I did try, and it doesn't seem to work with doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`, hence the question. Without any doctype, it works I must add.

Comment: @MLister If you have tried, please post some code that shows what you have tried so maybe we can help you figure out why it is not working.

Comment: @JoshMein, thanks. the question is updated.

Comment: @bfavaretto, just updated the question with further details. thanks.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see some of the code in your external files. Unless you would like to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks for providing the details. I'd add an answer, but Icarus basically said it. It should be working, if it's not, there's something else interfering. Perhaps you're not using the correct path to the CSS file? Try an absolute path. That said, consider using `.addClass` instead of `.attr` to manipulate classes with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. They will be referenced correctly. Many frameworks such as JQuery do this sort of thing to style the controls.